# Macbook air won't connect to Huawei phone's hot spot

Tags: macos, wifi

I have a macbook air 2015 and a Huawei Mate 20 lite phone. Macbook has latest Big Sur installed and the phone has Emui 10 (Android 10). No matter which frequency or band or security I choose the macbook won't connect to the phones hotspot. My fiancee has a Samsung and the macbook can connect to the Samsung's hot spot just fine. This is really inconvient for me. How can I fix this problem?

I should note my other laptop with Windows 10 installed can connect to my phone's hot spot.

Comment: Do you get an error message? What happens exactly when you try to connect?

Comment: It says "Connection unsuccessful" and nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

Somehow my macbook air made it's way into the forbidden list in my phone... I've been pulling my hair out for weeks.